# Separating specific values from a list in python

Tags: python, nested-loops

I have a list of lists(called table):

```
table = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [2, 3, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 3, 2], [1, 3, 3]]
```

where the first element of each sub list is the start point, the second is the endpoint and the third is the distance between the two points. So e.g. [0,1,2] means the gap between the point 0 and 1 is 2.

Now I want to use the information in table, to construct another list of lists(called distances) containing all the distances between all the points. So that, I could for example, call distances[0][2] (meaning I want the distance between point 0 and point 2, so the output should be 3).

However I am having trouble correctly separating the date from table and putting it into distances.
My code so far is this:

```
dstFromOnePoint = []
distances = []
numberOfPoints = 4 #0,1,2,3
for i in range(numberOfPoints): #loops through all start points
    for j in range(numberOfPoints): # loops through all endpoints
        for val in table: 
            if (val[0] == i and val[1] == j) or (val[0] == j and val[1] == i): # checks start node , end node
                dst = val[2]
                dstFromOnePoint.append(dst)
            elif (i==j): #distance from one point to itself will be 0
                dstFromOnePoint.append(0)
    distances.append(dstFromOnePoint)
print(distances)
print(distances[0][2])
```

The output I get:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
0
```

The output I should get:

```
[[0,2,3,2], [2,0,1,3], [3,1,0,2], [2,3,2,0]]
3
```

I think I'm using my loops incorrectly because I end up appending the same list multiple times, but even just looking at one individual sub list, I don't have the correct values, so I probably have more issues that I don't know how to fix?

Comment: Yes the loop is not used correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a correct and more compact solution:

```
numberOfPoints = 4
distances = [numberOfPoints * [0] for _ in range(numberOfPoints)]
for x, y, d in table:
   distances[x][y] = d
   distances[y][x] = d
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pre-populate the distance matrix and then assign per [i][j]

Fixes on your original solutions:

```
table = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [2, 3, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 3, 2], [1, 3, 3]]

distances = []
numberOfPoints = 4 #0,1,2,3
distances = [[0 for _ in range(numberOfPoints)] for _ in range(numberOfPoints)]
for i in range(numberOfPoints): #loops through all start points
    for j in range(numberOfPoints): # loops through all endpoints
        for val in table:
            if (val[0] == i and val[1] == j) or (val[0] == j and val[1] == i): # checks start node , end node
                dst = val[2]
                distances[i][j] = dst
            # actually you can drop this elif as distances is intitalized to 0
            elif (i==j): #distance from one point to itself will be 0
                # dstFromOnePoint.append(0)
                distances[i][j] = 0
    # distances.append(dstFromOnePoint)
print(distances)
print(distances[0][2])
```

gives:

```
[[0, 2, 3, 2], [2, 0, 1, 3], [3, 1, 0, 2], [2, 3, 2, 0]]
3
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one line using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

[[next(g)[2] if j!=i else 0 for j in range(len(table[0]) + 1 )] for  i, (k, g) in enumerate(groupby(sorted(e for f, s, t in table for e in [[f, s, t], [s, f, t]]), key=lambda x: x[0]))]
```

output:

```
[[0, 2, 3, 2], [2, 0, 1, 3], [3, 1, 0, 2], [2, 3, 2, 0]]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks I didn't realise it could be done in one line. However I think that is still a little to advanced for my level :) .